# Is there any way to make a function so players can't swim upwards in water, but instead just have a higher jump?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm making a custom underwater map in Minecraft and I'm trying to figure out if there's any way to make a function to where instead of swimming upwards underwater you just have a 2 block jump? I don't want people wandering outside of the map from being able to swim around. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minecraft 1.13 uses tags to identify characteristics of different blocks and entities. Amongst those are fluid tags for lava and water. If you reset the fluid tag for water in your datapack, then the game will treat water like air and you will be unable to swim.

Note that boats are no longer able to float and particles will disappear if you do this. Items also won't float and sponges are unable to remove water.

After that, it's just a matter of giving players who are inside a water block a jumpboost effect.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please consider accepting my answer using the check mark on the left. Then people who have the same question can see that you have an answer. I will elaborate my answer soon for the sake of completion.

Comment: Is there a specific name for just disabling fluids? Because the only datapack it lets me use is "vanilla" and that just makes everything go to garbage, like UI's not working and items not dropping. 

I just started getting back into command blocks and minecraft in general around a month ago so sorry that I don't know that much.

Comment: You need to make your own datapack. You need to make it anyway if you want to use functions. Disabling the vanilla datapack is indeed not adviced in this situation. You can make a "minecraft" namespace in your datapack and with that you can override the fluid tags by creating your own tags in the appropriate folder.